# How can I do this in a single mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
user table
========
id(int) | name(varchar)
------------------------
1       | user1
2       | some_other_user



product table
===============
id(int) | user_id(int) | product(varchar) | status(varchar)
------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1            | product1         | bought
2       | 1            | product3         | sold
3       | 2            | product22        | sold
4       | 2            | product2         | bought
5       | 2            | product4         | sold
6       | 1            | product5         | bought
7       | 1            | product7         | sold
```

I need to fetch the user's name, how many products he has, and how many of those products have a `status = sold`, with a single mysql query. Any ideas?

Comment: `status` should be normalized: you're wasting db space and you're prone to mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following query:

```
select 
    u.id, 
    u.name, 
    count(p.product) as totalproducts,
    sum(case when p.status = 'sold' then 1 else 0 end) as soldproducts
from user u
inner join product p on u.id=p.user_id
group by u.id, u.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, 
COUNT(p.id) AS totalproducts,
COUNT(IF(p.status="sold",p.user_id,NULL))
FROM users u
INNER JOIN products p ON p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```